# angular2 form + async validation + ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush = no view refresh?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

[angular2 RC4 + @angular/forms module]

I have a component using `OnPush` change detection containing a `FormGroup`.
This form contains a `FormControl` with an `async` validator.

When the validation is complete (no more `pending`), the view is not refresh.
Only the `input` blur event makes view refresh..

If I remove the `OnPush` change detection, it works properly.

[This plunker demonstrates it](https://plnkr.co/edit/dytSt4?p=preview).

Is it an angular bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the goal of using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.

You don't have any @Input property or `| async` pipe on your component, but it is only point of updating the view state with this strategy - when Input property updated (in ideal with a new object). So just get rid of it for current case

**UPDATE**

if you still insist on using OnPush in this case, for expected behavior you should trigger change detection manually.

Add `import {..., ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';` and inject instance of it in constructor.

In your method you have to add this:

```
 uniqueNameAsync(control: FormControl): Promise<{[key: string]:any}>{
   return new Promise(resolve => {
       setTimeout(() =>{
            resolve(null);
            this.changeRef.markForCheck();
      }, 500);
   });
 }
```

Comment: With `OnPush`, view refresh is trigger too when events happens inside the component like a click or an input typing. In the plunker, view is refresh when you begin typing ('pending' appears). And sync validators works well.. so I don't know if I can consider it like normal behavior or a bug with async validators..

Comment: Ok, so if you still insist on using OnPush in this case, for expected behavior you should trigger change detection manually.

Add `import {..., ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';` and inject instance of it in constructor.

In your method you have to add this:

     `setTimeout(() =>{
                resolve(null);
                this.changeRef.markForCheck();
      }, 500)`

Comment: Async execution only invokes change detection in `OnPush` when used with `| async` which is not possible in this case. I also think you need to invoke change detection manually.

Comment: ok thanks guys! I'm using ngrx/store and trying to use `onPush` almost everywhere. It would be nice to have ng2 forms implemented this under the hood because it could knows 'things happens' inside the component after async validation..